# Mutex.ReleaseMutex() gives Synchronization error even when the same thread owns it

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have created a separate dependency that does the locking and unlocking and the choice of implementation is Mutex class in .NET.

```
interface ISynchronize 
{
  void Lock(lockId);
  void Release(lockId);
}
```

The application uses this dependency to acquire and release locks like so

```
Trace.WriteLine($"LOCK ({System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}) Before locking Star ID {starId}");
this.Synchronizer.Lock(starId);
Trace.WriteLine($"LOCK ({System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}) After locking Star ID {starId}");

SomeWorkToBeDone();

Trace.WriteLine($"LOCK ({System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}) Before Releasing Star ID {starId}");
this.Synchronizer.Release(starId);
Trace.WriteLine($"LOCK ({System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}) After Releasing Star ID {starId}");
```

The system intermittently generates an exception with the following traces

```
LOCK (53) Before locking Star ID 1 
LOCK (53) After locking Star ID 1 
LOCK (53) Before Releasing Star ID 1 
Exception thrown: 'System.ApplicationException' in mscorlib.dll 
Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
```

Notice the thread IDs are same, so no one could say that the the thread that is attempting to release it  may not own it. What else could be going on? Shall I not create new object and use `TryOpenExisting`?

Here is the implementation of the dependency

```
public void Lock(string lockId)
{
    var mutex = new Mutex(false, lockId);

    if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToWait)) == false)
    {
        throw new SynchronizationTimedOutException($"Could not acquire lock within configured {secondsToWait} second(s)");
    }
}

public void Release(string lockId)
{
    var mutex = new Mutex(false, lockId);

    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: I suspect the mutex is being garbage collected between the calls to `Lock` and `Release`, and as `Release` indicates it doesn't want to take initial ownership if creating the mutex then you'll get the exception when calling `ReleaseMutex'

Comment: @Sean Good point. Should I store the reference to the mutex in Thread-Local Storage (TLS)? or should I change the signature of Lock to return a Mutex object and make Release accept that object so that we can be sure the Mutex object is not GC`d.

Comment: It depends. It's not clear from the example why you need the mutex in the fist place. If you're expecting to release the mutex on a different threadto the one that locks it then TLS won't help. One option is to store them in a Dictionary<string, Mutex> and manage that.

Comment: @Sean Mutex is for doing mutual exclusions. The application gets bombarded with data for stars and provides a star's unique ID. We need to synchronize so that one request of a star at a time is entertained.

Comment: @Sean Your theory checks out. We are now doing something to preserve the references.